# Persistent Connection with OnReceived response

Tags: promise, signalr, persistent-connection, pipelining

I'm just starting to learn about "Persistant Connections" in SignalR and like for instance that I'm able to send out pre-serialized json.

But this method of sending from the client, receiving serverside and then send back any respons again is a bit counterintuitive to work with.

Is there any way if doing some simple basic piepelineing on top of "Persistant Connections" without resorting back to Hubs?

I just want to be able to do something like this:

```
connection.send({ 'command': 123 }).then(function (confirmation) {
            if (!confirmation.ok) alert('Command failed');
        });
```

Also, if an exception is thrown in the servers OnReceived, where does it go? Is it swallowed by SignalR? Do I have to catch and send back some kind of error-object myself?

Comment: 9 months later... Did you ever solve this?